# Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to use an IF statement for multiple criteria? or what would I be best using... I have tried to amend the question with what I'm looking to do the code isnt correct in this but it may highlight more what Im looking to achieve.

If(A3="Dog","Dog Green","Dog Blue"),Matches,doesn’t match)

For some reason it wont let me upload a picture....

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you clarify what you want it to look like? Is dog frog bug... in the same cell or different cells? And the output same question?

Comment: o didnt realise that never included my table nope all in seperate cells...

Comment: Can you post an image of your table, and a sample of what the outcome should be? Is "Dog" above "cat" in your list, so therefore "dog matches cat"? How do you know what matches what?

Comment: it looks like above now... I am trying to locate every time the word dog is mentioned (this also needs to pick up dog blue and dog yellow) but I dont want a count i need the word matches or doesnt match to appear in the next column

Comment: Your data example is confusing. To simplify, assume you are checking for "cat", "dog", and "frog". Do you simply want to see whether each of those appears anywhere in your data list at least once? Or do you want to see which animal appears in each element of your data list?

Comment: I'm having to use this example as I cant give out the actual information... I shall try and amend my question and see if that helps

Comment: Just a note - if you don't say "@USERNAME" in a comment, it won't tell that person that you have a comment for them to look at. Also, when you edit your post it doesn't tell anyone about it. So generally, if you update your question to respond to someone's request, it is best to edit the question, and then add a comment to the question saying "@USERNAME please see edits above" or something like that. Anyway, could you take a look at my answer below? If it isn't quite what you want please add a comment for me there so I can clarify for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to test for multiple criteria in Excel. Probably the easiest would be either to:

Use the AND / OR BOOLEAN operaters. AND(test1,test2...) checks to see whether each of test1 & test2 are TRUE (can hold as many arguments as you need). ie:

```
=if(And(A1="dog",B1="cat"),"there is a cat and a dog", "there is not both a cat and a dog")
```

OR(test1,test2) checks to see whether either test1 is TRUE, or test2 is TRUE, or if both are true. ie:

```
=if(Or(A1="dog",B1="cat"),"There is either a cat, or there is a dog, or both","there is neither a cat nor a dog")
```

Another broad option is to 'nest' one IF statement inside of another. ie:

```
=if(A1="dog","There is a dog. Have not checked for cats",if(B1="cat","A1 is not a dog, and also B1 is a cat","There is neither a cat nor a dog"))
```

If you have more specific questions you should update your question with all possible details you have.

Comment: Not sure why I've been downvoted here; when the OP originally posted his/her question it vaguely asked how to do an IF statement with multiple criteria. Still waiting on further elaboration from OP as to what s/he actually wants.

Comment: I was working through your suggestions and the one that seems to work for me in the 'nest' one IF statement it seems to do exactly what i'm looking for... thankyou very much for all your help! @ Grade 'Eh' Bacon

Comment: @Paula glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

This will definitely work:

```
=IF(OR(A3="Dog",A3="Dog Green",A3="Dog Blue"),"Matches","doesn’t match")
```

just ad OR statement inside IF Statement
Don't forget to use Quotation marks also

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple formula you could have found on google:

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND("dog",A1))
```

Will return True if dog is in A1 and false if it is not.

For further reading (well explained) https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text

Also, it seems to me like this is a single-criteria. What do you mean by multiple criteria?

Comment: Based on OP's edits, it looks like he has a list of items in different cells, and not a list of items in a single cell.